# Better way of getting information from a table using XPath in python?

Tags: python, html, dom, xpath

If you have a look at this website: http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57109

The second table information is what i need.

What i am doing right now:

I am going through every cell in the column **Tid** to match a specific date. If it matches then it goes on to extract other relevant data from that row. The code for that looks like this:

```
rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table[2]/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))

time_xpath = XPath("td[1]/span/span//text()[2]")
team_xpath = XPath("td[2]/a/text()")

html = lxml.html.parse(url)
league_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/h1//text()")

divName = league_xpath(html)[0]

trash, divisionName = divName.rsplit("- ")

dict[divisionName] = {}

for i,row in enumerate(rows_xpath(html)):
    .... doing some stuff here
```

**Problem:** 
As time goes another table will be inserted to the webpage meaning **rows_xpath** will be invalid since it will be needed to change to this:

```
rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table[3]/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))
```

what is changed is the table[x] where x is the number being changed.

Is there a smart solution to solve this or even a better way of getting the information that i need in a more secure way that is not depending of the XPath? I appreciate all help i can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily have to specify the `table` element number - if you are simply looking for unique date values among all tables.

```
rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))
```

This would return a collection of rows with that date value, among however many tables there may be.  If, however, you are looking for dates on a specific table, you may have to select the table with an xpath first (assuming there are some unique values you can use), then use an xpath within that table.

Comment: Thank you, you have been a great help!